# Suggestions for a reading list in Statistics and intro to machine learning

Tags: statistics, soft-question, book-recommendation, machine-learning, advice

I have built a reading list based on recommendations and suggestions found on several posts from this community. My intention is to use this reading list to acquire a good understanding about statistics and also about some topics on machine learning. Being my final goal to start a PhD in Statistics (in around 2 years).

I'm familiar with basic calculus and basic Linear Algebra (almost all the concepts covered by Gilbert Strang books, even though in a practical level). Furthermore, I'm familiar with basic concepts of probability and statistics. Additionally, I'm highly proficient in R and Python (and I have some experience using numpy, matplotlib, pandas and scikit-learn).

For this reason, I would appreciate further suggestions and recommendations, in order to improve this reading list.

The books on this reading list range from introductory to more advanced level, being the following:

1. Gilbert Strang - Calculus
2. Daniel J. Velleman - How to Prove It: A Structured Approach
3. Gilbert Strang - Linear Algebra and Its Applications
4. Larry Wasserman - All of Statistics
5. James, Witten, Hastie and Tibshirani - An Introduction to Statistical Learning
6. Kreyszig - Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications [chapters 1 to 3]
7. Golub and Van Loan - Matrix Computations
8. Stein and Shakarchi - Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces
9. Jan R. Magnus - Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics
10. Fitzpatrick - Advanced Calculus
11. Wakerly, Mendenhall and Scheaffer - Mathematical Statistics with Applications
12. Casella and Berger - Statistical Inference
13. Boyd and Vandenberghe - Convex Optimization
14. Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman - The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction
15. Gelman et al. - Bayesian Data Analysis
16. Kevin Murphy - Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective

[Click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNpBr.png) to see a visual representation of the previous reading list

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Added Hans Engler Feedback

Edit 2: Added All of Statistics as suggested by Wanshan

Edit 3: Added paf feedback

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. In order to get meaningful feedback, you should also state what your current level of mathematical knowledge is. Do you know Calculus? Do you know any matrix algebra? Do you know any probability theory? Do you know how to program in R or Python? And what are your goals: Understand and appreciate? Prepare for further training? Become a practitioner? Become a researcher? Personally, I would put Fitzpatrick near the bottom and Kreyszig, Golub/Van Loan, Velleman as well. And I would include Hastie, Tibshirani, Witten: ISLR.

Comment: As well as textbooks you might consider including journal papers as you get to the more advanced level, both [JMLR](http://www.jmlr.org/) and [NIPS](https://papers.nips.cc/) are freely available online

Comment: I recommend All of Statistics by Larry Wasserman. It covers so many topics you can encounter in statisitcs and machine learning, while keeping the math at a appropriate level for beginners.

Comment: You'll need **optimization**: Lagrange multipliers, why not Karush-Kuhn-Tucker, maybe some basic convex optimization and **gradient descent**: it's very important in deep learning! Moreover, I don't think you need all what is covered by a Functional Analysis course like Kreyszig's (a quick look tells me that chapters 1 to 3 are sufficient). One key idea you should keep from linear algebra is **orthogonal projections**, esp. applied to **conditional expectation**, least squares... 1/2

Comment: (continued) If you intend to go into a PhD, maybe it can be theoretically-oriented and investing in **Lebesgue integration theory** and after Probability (up to Markov chains) from this viewpoint will be important. But if you're less theoretically-oriented in your studies, Wasserman's great book may be sufficient to avoid you this (maybe) painful theory. Last point: you say you're good with Python. But do you know **numpy, matplotlib, pandas, scikit-learn**? (The last two should be seen after you begin statistics). 2/2

Comment: [Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms - Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/)

Comment: I would suggest replacing Boyd's book with Bertsekas'. Boyd's is extremely superficial.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you the book [Practical Econometrics with Python](https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/product/B08KJ1322G?ref_=dbs_m_mng_rwt_calw_tkin_0&storeType=ebooks). The book links theory with practical examples in Python from most basic topics like OLS to advanced topics like VARMA.